# Objects being added to separate arrays instead of pushed to single array (PapaParse)

Tags: javascript, json, papaparse

I am trying to push all of my JSON objects to one array using Papa Parse however I am only able to push them to separate arrays at the moment. As you can see I am converting a CSV file into JSON.

Here is my code:

```
var myRows = [];
Papa.parse("/drivencarstock.csv", {
  download: true,
  header: true,
    step: function(row) {
        myRows.push(row.data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      var newMessageRef = rootRef.push();
      newMessageRef.set(myRows);
      console.log(myRows);

    }
});
```

I am just wondering how I can put all of these JSON objects that Papa Parse is parsing into one array instead of one for each object?

Here is what my console looks like:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.